# Octave/Matlab: Arranging Space-Time Data in a Matrix

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, octave

This is a question about coding common practice, not a specific error or other malfunctions.

I have a matrix of values of a variable that changes in space and time. What is the common practice, to use different columns for time or space values?

If there is a definite common practice, in the first place

**Update:** Here is an example of the data in tabular form. The time vector is much longer than the space vector.

```
t  y(x1)  y(x2)
1  100    50
2  100    50
3  100    50
4  99     49
5  99     49
6  99     49
7  98     49
8  98     48
9  98     48
10 97     48
```

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: if `t` is a vector where the difference between to values is constant, you shouldn't save it as vector but as range (your "space" data is equidistant (in time) sampled)

Comment: Yes, in the actual code I have time as a range. The data above is for illustration purposes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your goal and ultimately doesn't matter that much. This is more the question of your convenience.

If you do care about the performance, there is a slight difference. Your code achieves maximum cache efficiency when it traverses monotonically increasing memory locations. In Matlab data stored column-wise, therefore [processing data column-wise results in maximum cache efficiency.](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/programming-patterns-maximizing-code-performance-by-optimizing-memory-access.html) Thus, if you frequently access all the data at certain time layers, store space in columns. If you frequently access all the data at certain spatial points, store time in columns.

Comment: What I need is data for the whole timespan at a specific location. So I'll arrange the matrix as the example above. Thanks.